# How to use Tokens [current page arguments]?

Tags: 8

I dont know how to use tokens to get arguments from url.

I have url: **site/country**

On this page i have links to terms, i want them to have in alias first argument from current page **/country/term-name**.

But instead of this my terms have alias **/batch/term-name**
Can i have a little help and show me a little example of how to use tokens of current

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use tokens with taxonomy terms urls you have to enable token, pathauto and Chaos tools module. You can do it by runing drush command 
**drush en pathauto -y**
After these modules are enabled go to admin/config/search/path/patterns
[image]

[image]

[image]

Hope this is what you asked about.